# Android custom View dimensions and canvas coordinates

Tags: android, android-layout, bitmap, android-canvas, android-view

I have custom View that should paint a bitmap. I've created a simple line(bmp 1x50 px) to check where will be drawn exactly. In my `onDraw(Canvas c)` I'm using this line of code:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, paint);
```

Where paint is simple Paint object, without any fancy settings. The problem is that this line shows at the middle of the view, not on top, as I thought it would be.

I'm setting View properties in layout xml:

```
<com.example.CustomView
    android:id="@+id/costom_view"
    android:layout_width="230px"
    android:layout_height="188px"
    android:layout_marginTop="10px"
    custom:srcDraw="@drawable/menu_indicators_level_draw_up" />
```

This custom property is the ID of the bitmap I use to draw on canvas.

Why won't the View behave properly? And why does my canvas have a size if 800x450 (size of the screen i suppose) and not 230x188 like I defined in the layout?

And very important thing, I want to multiply the same bitmap on this view many times. At the end of work I want to draw this line from bottom to top of my View.

Comment: could you pkease post your onDraw method

Comment: In `onDraw()` i only draw this one line as I mentioned, there is only `canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, paint);`, bitmap is initialized from resources in constructor, as well as `paint = new Paint()`,  thats all.

Answer (score 1):

i think what you should use to draw the line above the bitmap is the follwing :

```
drawLine(float startX, float startY, float stopX, float stopY, Paint paint)
```

and give it the right coordinates to be drawn on top of the bitmap .

Hope that helps .

Comment: Ok, that is good start, this is painted properly, I discovered that my line bitmap was drown inproperly (it was 1 poxel width line but i tave bigger background, transparent) so image was not 1x50 but 50x50. That cause diferrence in dimensions and coordinates.

Comment: Yep, thanks for your help. Now i have properly created bitmap and everything works fine. Your answer is correct but it not solved my problem(if i wanted to change colour of line i'd have to change code, in my case i can only change file in res folder).